# How do I validate a checkbox value in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following `ViewModel`

```
public class ReportFilters
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime From { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime To { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
}
```

I pass either the value `1` or `0` when I call this route to `IsCorrect` but the `ModelState.IsValid` is always returning false.

This started to happen after I added `public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }`

Here is how my controller action look like

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult GetTotals([Bind(Include = "From,To,UserId,IsCorrect ")] ReportFilters reportFilters)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SomeModel results;

        if(reportFilters.IsCorrect)
        {
            results = conn.Database.SqlQuery<SomeModel>(SomeQuery, from, to).ToList();
        } else 
        {
            results = conn.Database.SqlQuery<SomeModel>(SomeOtherQuery, from, to).ToList();
        }

        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(new { }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

**Question**

How can I correctly validate the value of a check box? If the value is `1` then it should be `true` otherwise `false`.

Comment: Could you take out `[Bind(Include = "From,To,UserId,IsCorrect ")]`, and try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ensure You Are Passing Your Parameters Properly**

Have you tried passing `true` or `false` explicitly (i.e. `Controller/Action?IsCorrect=true`) as opposed to a 0 or 1?

A checkbox should always bind directly to a boolean value. You'll just need to ensure that the `name` attribute of your checkbox matches your parameter or model property exactly (i.e. `IsCorrect`) :

```
<!-- Using a plain CheckBox -->
<input name='IsCorrect' type='checkbox' />
<!-- Using an HTML Helper -->
@Html.CheckBox("IsCorrect")
```

You can [see a working example demonstrating this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ggN6Aq) below :

[image]

Comment: using the value `true` and `false` worked. but if I pass `false` the the `ModelState.IsValid` will also return false. The check box should be optional and not required

Comment: There isn't anything within your model that would cause it to be invalid just because of the `IsCorrect` property. However, you'll need to make sure that you pass along the other properties as those are decorated with `[Required]` tags and thus will cause validation errors if empty / null.

Comment: I am positing using ajax request via `jQuery`  something like this ` if ($('#CorrectDispositions').is(':checked'))
             return "true"; else return "false";`

Comment: The `is()` function will return a boolean value, so if you are planning on passing that, you might explicitly indicate that it is bound to your `IsCorrect` property (i.e. `{ /* Other data here */ , IsCorrect : $('#CorrectDispositions').is(':checked') }`)